# Zend Framework Plugin Package Loader

Tags: php, zend-framework, plugins, modularity

The challenge:

I want to modularize my library folder in my zend framework app. This is fine, if you want to put everything in the same namespace such "App_." But the problem comes in when you have a dozen packages such as a SignUp package, ACL Package, Navigation Package, Foo Package etc. Now each packages has some view helpers, some controller plugins, some action helpers plus some other base classes. You could add each view helper path individually, but that could junk up your application.ini file/ bootstrap.

So the question is, is anyone aware of 'Plugin Package' loader for ZF?

To clarify, it would be nice to have a resource plugin that you pass the package name, it adds the namespace, registers some default options like helper paths and then you can configure it to add helpers to Action Helper brokers. Each plugin package might have to have its own ini file or an init class that where the programmer could initialize the plugin package. Any thoughts or knowledge of something like this would be appreciated.

Comment: Not sure if this will help you, but did you consider writing custom autoloader. An example for PhpThumb is http://goo.gl/cxj7P

Comment: @Marcin: I like your suggestion. I think its a piece of the puzzle. However, I'm looking for a full feature plugin package loader.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is difficult to find a solution to. ZF doesn't seem to be used in the manner you wish.

For example you want the following packages

1. Navigation
2. ACL
3. Sign Up

These are all completely separate and don't all 'plugin' to ZF in a similar manner.

1. Navigation needs to be stored and built for each request that needs the package, the navigation object then needs to be used in `Zend_View` objects or perhaps not. What happens when the navigation is referenced in a view but it doesn't exist?
2. The ACL package is so specific, it integrates into ZF in a lot of different ways, it needs a `Zend_Controller_Plugin`, it needs a way of meaningful way of storing and building the `Zend_Acl` object for querying on an application to application basis.
3. Sign Up needs a controller, an action and a form which is passed to `Zend_View` and the form needs to be process. This then needs to be plugged into your ACL object, presumably a database and perhaps various other parts of your site it it requires more specific permissions that fall outside of the use for ACL

Its not impossible to do what you want, but there must be a better way. It almost sounds like your trying to build a CMS with optional, plug-able packages?

The ACL issue I have resolved by having a Library of controllers, helpers, models, forms, etc. A `Zend_Controller_Plugin` runs and attempts to log in the user, this plugin is run for every app I create, it works well uses an ACL object format which I have used for a while.

For Sign Up I have a `RegisterController` in my Library, if my application requires registration it has its own `RegisterController` which extends the `RegisterController` in the Library. If the application doesn't need registration then it doesn't have its own `RegisterController`.

I hope that helps, I really think that doing this in the abstracted way suggested isn't worth it and will never be so solid and tight you can truly rely on it because each application is specific.

Comment: +1 for being so thorough and thoughtful. I'm not looking to build a cms, I want these packages to be "abstract" and left up to the programmer to implement and add business logic. Although CMS package with dependent packages may be an option. One such app built on ZF is Tomato CMS[http://www.tomatocms.com/en_US/].

Answer (score 0):

Generally, in this case you should use modules which are already modularized instead of modularizing the library.

```
modules/
   signup/
     models/
     plugins/
```

The default module resource autoloader is configured by default to load plugins:

See: http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.loader.autoloader-resource.html:

If you really need to modularize the library, the customized autoloader will be the best solution (there is an easy to extend abstract autoloader).

You may also consider separate library for each module, added to your include path (not recommended, because it will slow down the app):

```
modules/
   signup/
     models/
     library/
```